# Displaying database content to textbox using option tag PHP

Tags: php, html, sql, select, drop-down-menu

im a complete beginner in PHP programming.. and i create a simple add/edit/delete in php.. i was wondering if you could help me convert this to a simple search program using select/option tag. My goal is when i choose a name in the  tag, the database fields will appear in the textbox.

index.php

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> 
<table align="center">
<tr>
<td>Members:</td>
<td>
<select id="choice" name="choice">
<option value="kelvin">Aljohn Kelvin</option>
<option value="belen">Belen</option>
<option value="keneth">Aldrin Keneth</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Firstname:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="fname" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Lastname:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="lname" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email Address:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="email" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>City / Address:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="address" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" /></td>
</tr>
</table>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
include 'database.php';
$firstname=$_POST['fname'];
$lastname=$_POST['lname'];
$emailadd=$_POST['email'];
$cityaddress=$_POST['address'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tblinfo`(Firstname,Lastname,Email,Address)
VALUES('$firstname','$lastname','$emailadd','$cityaddress')");

}
?>                        
</form>

<table align="center">
<?php
include("database.php");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblinfo");

while($test = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$id = $test['UserID'];
echo "<tr align = 'center'>";
echo "<td><font color = 'black'>" .$test['UserID']."</font></td>";
echo "<td><font color = 'black'>" .$test['Firstname']."</font></td>";
echo "<td><font color = 'black'>`enter code here`" .$test['Lastname']."</font></td>";
echo "<td><font color = 'black'>" .$test['Email']."</font></td>";
echo "<td><font color = 'black'>" .$test['Address']."</font></td>";
echo "<td> <a href='view.php?UserID=$id'>Edit</a>";
echo "<td> <a href='delete.php?UserID=$id'><center>Delete</center></a>";

echo "</tr>";
}
mysql_close($connect);
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

view.php

```
<?php
require("database.php");
$id = $_REQUEST['UserID'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblinfo WHERE UserID = '$id'");
$test = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if(!$result){
die ("ERROR: Data Not Found!");
}
$FirstName = $test['Firstname'];
$LastName = $test['Lastname'];
$EmailAdd = $test['Email'];
$CityAddress = $test['Address'];


if(isset($_POST['save'])){
$firstname_save = $_POST['fname'];
$lastname_save = $_POST['lname'];
$email_save = $_POST['email'];
$address_save = $_POST['address'];
mysql_query("UPDATE tblinfo SET Firstname = '$firstname_save',Lastname = '$lastname_save',Email = '$email_save',Address = '$address_save' WHERE UserID = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());
echo "Saved!";

header("Location: index.php");
}
mysql_close($connect);
?>
```

delete.php

```
<?php
include("database.php");
$id = $_REQUEST['UserID'];

mysql_query("DELETE FROM tblinfo WHERE UserID = '$id'") or die(mysql_error()); //sending query to delete

header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

database.php

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

if(!$connect){
die('Could not connect to database! ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("kelvindb", $connect);
?>
```

Comment: This will require client side code, ie. javascript, in order to populate the form fields when a `select::option` is selected. Attempt some code and then update your answer if you have issues.

Comment: by the way.. i have updated the my post.. i paste all of my codes and php codes that i had written.. for me to easily grasp things out.. thank you.. sorry im a complete and utterly a beginner in php..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selected name should be sent to php code using AJAX, Here you will use the name to fetch rest of the things from your database and return it back to JavaScript (using AJAX). Now, you can give the values to individual input text boxes (i.e. email, address, lname, fname) using simple javascript.

Function callToAjax() should be called whenever option is selected.

```
function callToAjax()
{
   var selectID = document.getElementById("choice");
   var name= selectID.options[selectID.selectedIndex].value;
   var data="fullName="+name;
   $.ajax({  
     type: 'POST',  
     url: 'fileNameWhereFetchFromDatabaseIsPerformed.php', 
     data: data,
     success: function(response)
     {
        /* response will be sent as a json array from
           fileNameWhereFetchFromDatabaseIsPerformed.php where 
           (key,value) pair will be stored, use it to assign values to each 
           textbox.*/
       document.getElementByName('fname').Value = response['fname'];
       document.getElementByName('lname').Value = response['lname'];
       document.getElementByName('email').Value = response['email'];
       document.getElementByName('address').Value = response['address'];

     }
   });
}
```

Now use the following code in fileNameWhereFetchFromDatabaseIsPerformed.php:

```
<?php
$names = explode(" ",$_POST['fullName']);

$returnArray = array();
$returnArray['fname']=$names[0];
$returnArray['lname']=$names[1];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT email, address FROM tblinfo WHERE fname = $returnArray['fname'] and lname= $returnArray['lname']");
if (!$result) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

$returnArray['email'] = $row[0]; 
$returnArray['address'] = $row[1]; 

echo json_encode($returnArray);

?>
```

I believe things would work fine.

Comment: i have tried it sir.. but somehow i got an error like this.. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\activity\KELVIN\index.php on line 87
_____________
and by the way.. i have updated the my post.. i paste all of my codes and php codes that i had written.. for me to easily grasp things out.. thank you..

Comment: It is because of some quote error in the select query. Play around with some quotes in query and search this error on stackoverflow. I am sure you will be able to solve it.

Comment: okay.. thanks sir.. would you mind pointing out where should i paste the code.?? 'fileNameWhereFetchFromDatabaseIsPerformed.php' is giving me goosebumps there..hahaha.. :D i edited my question and paste all my coding that i have done.. thank you..!!

Comment: First of all, change this filename, Give some name which matches your requirement. I gave such name so that you can understand the purpose of this file. You need to create a new file and paste this php code in that. After that include the javascript function in your js file. Make sure you change the name of file in that js function as well.